# GScript: Track number of emails sent using mass email Gscript code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to modify this GScript to count the number of emails sent. I would like to track the total number of emails sent using this function. Would it be easier to do it within this code or to use a code to search the sent box of the user? I believe I know how to make a count value get stored temporarily, but I am unsure how to store it for a greater period of time.

```
function WhiteTicket() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Email Outline');
var lastRow = sheet.getRange("J1").getValue();
var range = sheet.getRange("A3:"+ lastRow);
var UserData = range.getValues();
for (i in UserData) {
var row = UserData[i];
var firstname = row[1];
var lastname = row[2]; 
var email = row[3];
var whiteticket = row[6];
if (whiteticket != '0') {
var esubject = "New Tickets";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: row[3],
  subject: esubject,
  htmlBody:"Hello " + firstname + "," + '<br />'+'<br />' + 
    "Please note that you have " + whiteticket + " ticket(s)."});
}
}
    if (ok) {
    EmailComplete();;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Record amount of emails sent by this script.

---

#### Solution:

Use `GmailApp.search()` and pass to `length` to count the amount of emails sent.

---

#### Example:

```
var total = GmailApp.search('in:sent subject:"'+esubject+'"').length;
Logger.log(total);
```

This is pretty self explanatory, it'll search all of the emails in your sent folder with subject matching the subject string you're assigning with `var esubject`. The script above just writes it to the log using `Logger.log()`.

Comment: Something I failed to mention is that I have multiple users using this Macro in the same workbook. Would it search all their sent boxes?

Comment: It would search the sent label of the user running the script, then provide the total sent for that user alone.